# Jboss Error-Cannot process metadata

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, netbeans6.8, jboss5.x

I'm trying to implement stateless session bean ejb3 in jboss5 using netbeans6.8 as a editor. When I tried deploying my application, I'm getting the following error. What is the issue with this?

```
17:45:04,901 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfszip:/E:/Shalini/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/InsighIT1.1-ejb.jar/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:181)
        at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:93)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tomcat.Main from BaseClassLoader@1d6d136{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@41312b{name=vfszip:/E:/hh/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/InsighIT1.1-ejb.jar/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my jar file is corrupted. That's y I faced this problem. Thanks everyone...

Comment: What do you mean corrupted? How did you fix it?